# Looping 2 columns from an excel file into matlab

Tags: matlab

For my experiment, I am presenting participants with different images (which are numbered from 1 to 324) in a scrambled order. My goal is to overlay their gaze pattern with a saliency map.

So I have two variables in MATLAB that I want to FOR loop:
"z" is the scrambled presentation order, ex: [95,147,1...] (324 numbers in total)
"i" is the order of gaze patterns recorded (it goes in order from 1 to 324)

I have tried use 2 for loops,

```
for z=[95,147,1....]
       for i=1:324
%open and create saliency maps for "z"
%open gaze pathways for "i"
%combine both 
%save
```

What I was hoping was that z=95 would be paired with i=1, z=147 would be paired with i=2 and so on, however what happens is the for loop goes through i=1:324 for all of z=95 and then continues to z=147 and goes through i=1:324 again...

I have thought of putting z and i values into a table such that

```
ImageOrder    ScatterOrder
95                1
147               2
1                 3
```

However, I have been having difficulty for the specific steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out a method,

I set

```
s1='A2' %first cell of the image order column
s2='B2' %first cell of the scatter order column
```

Then I create one for loop for 
    i=2:___(The row number I want to end on)

```
s1=['A', num2str(i)]; %Loops through rows of A
s2=['B', num2stri(i)]; %Loops through rows of B

x1=xlsread('filename.xls',[s1,':',s2]); 
a=x1(:,1) %Taking image order of every row 
b=x1(:,2); %Taking scatter order of every row
```

With the 'a' and 'b' then I can access two different variables in the same rows while it loops.